# Missing `(` in the placeholder when building a custom view

Tags: bug, status-completed, custom-questions-list

It seems that `(` is missing in the placeholder

[image]

[image]

Comment: How to get this option for "Custom Views"?

Comment: @CinCout You need to opt-in to get this feature, see "Edit Profile & Settings > Site Settings > Preferences > Custom Question Lists".

Comment: Personally, I'd say it's a stray ) and not a missing (. It's already greyed out and doesn't need parentheses imo. Maybe they had a discussion about it and decided to go 50/50.

Comment: Ah, is this feature why "Newest" no longer pays any attention whatsoever to my Watched Tags list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed. #TeamStrayEndParen